# I am trying to send a snmp message via snmptrap

Tags: snmp

I am trying to send an snmp message with snmptrap from the commandline, and the manual isn't super clear.

I have managed to send the example message successfully (10.0.0.1 == where I'm sending the messages to)

```
snmptrap -v 1 -c private 10.0.0.1 NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB::netSnmpExampleHeartbeatNotification "" 6 17 "" netSnmpExampleHeartbeatRate i 13546
```

But when I want to send a resynchronisation message such as:

```
snmptrap -v 1 -c private 10.0.0.1 HW-IMAPV1NORTHBOUND-TRAP-MIB::hwNmNorthboundEventSynchronizationCommandStart
```

I need to add a few more arguements.  I've tried adding myip:myport:date:date or just myip:myport, but no success.  I'm not too clear on what should be the following arguements. The man page:

```
snmptrap -v 1 [COMMON OPTIONS] [-Ci] enterprise-oid agent generic-trap specific-trap uptime [OID TYPE VALUE]
```

What should be the generic-trap, specific-trap etc?

From the MIB files:

: 1.3.6.1.4.1.2011.2.15.1.7.7.4

hwNmNorthboundEventSynchronizationCommandStart OBJECT-TYPE
                        SYNTAX OCTET STRING
                        ACCESS read-write
                        STATUS mandatory
                        DESCRIPTION

Format to omit dst flag:- IP:port:start time:end time:timezone, will consider the dstflag to be 0

Does someone have a bit more experience than me with SNMP to understand what I need to put in the command line arguements?

thanks!

Comment: This seems to be a question about the command line tool net-snmp and/or the network protocol SNMP, not about programming.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I should delete this question, or leave it, but my problem was partly because somehow the mib file was no read, and I had to use the OID directly. Otherwise the "arguments" depends on the mib file, the 6 is always 6, the 17 on the otherhand should correspond to the last number in the oid of the mib..